# Why is my avocado tree dropping its leaves?

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees, leaves, tree-care, avocado

I live in S. Florida (zone 10B). We planted a grafted avocado this past May. All year it's been doing pretty well, and we got a few small fruits a few weeks ago. Shortly after harvest, it started to drop leaves. Now most of the leaves have fallen, and the remaining are mostly wilted.

We're in the annual transition from wet to dry season, so I gave it a little extra water to make sure it wasn't just too dry. I noticed that it had some damage to the bark near the base, so I'm going to protect that and advise the lawn service to be more careful with the weed whackers. I also think it could use just a drop of fertilizer, since it's been in the ground 5 months now.

[image: Whole Tree]

[image: Wilted leaf]

[image: Wilted brown leaf]

[image: Injured trunk]

Anything else I should be checking for or doing?

Comment: The tree is not staked to best practices but this looks more like a bacterial wilt.